# How did Python called un-imported module?

Tags: python, python-module

I used:

```
import urllib.request
```

And then:

```
d={'value':12345}
urllib.parse.urlencode(d)
```

I expected python to throw an exception because I didn't imported urllib.parse but instead it worked.
What is the reason for it?

P.S: I am using Python 3.3.3

Answer (score 3):

Here is the relevant structure for the urllib package in Python 3.3.3

```
urllib/
    __init__.py   <-- empty file
    request.py
    parse.py
```

There's a line near the top of the `request` module which looks like:

```
from urllib.parse import some, helper, functions
```

And it's this line that is the cause of `urllib.parse` being brought into scope.

You can check that executing `import urllib.parse`, on the other hand, *does not* trigger an import of `urllib.request`.  It will necessarily bind the `urllib` name (because `urllib.parse` itself is not a valid identifier)  but it won't import any other submodules.

---

*Note*: had you done either of the following

```
import urllib.request as urllib_dot_request
from urllib import request
```

Then you would have neither `urllib` nor `urllib.parse` available in the namespace.  They would still get imported by the module loader, but wouldn't be brought into scope.